# How to test a regression model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

i'm new to python and tensorflow.
I follow the cifar10 example to build my own regression problem:
   read binary files; pack to batch; MSE training.

Now in the test stage, is there a way to write regression result streams to a binary file? Most examples are about classification, they only need return a accuracy.
So is there any examples?
Much thanks!

Comment: does it print out the train/test MSE somewhere?

Comment: yes, the mse value descents normally. what i want is the prediction value steam : n dims each frame.